# JMeter - run single thread with one request by defined time

Tags: jmeter

I have total of 5 requests.

First one is login and it returns JSON response with a token. I will extract the token using `JSON Extractor` which is to be sent in header as a `Authorization key` for all other request.

Now, first 4 requests would be working simultaneously but the 5th one will run between a given time period. E.g. I run 100 thread with ramp-up period 50 secs. and the 5th request must be executed after every 5 secs.

So, my question is How to run that 5th request every 5 secs while running the thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your scenario is not compatible with the JMeter's thread model, you cannot slow down only one request in the [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) without slowing down the rest.

You could consider moving the 5th request to another Thread Group and configure the desired requests rate by adding a [Constant Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Constant_Timer) or a [Constant Throughput Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeters-throughput-constant-timer/).

In order to pass the token between 1st and 2nd Thread Groups you can use [__setProperty() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__setProperty) in the 1st Thread Group to convert the variable holding the token into a JMeter Property, once done the value can be read via [__P() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) in the 2nd Thread Group.

Comment: Thanks Dmitri. I tried same with Constant Timer and working as expected.